# Wrap list elements into objects for JSON field - Mysql8

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

Is it possible to present this fragment from JSON field:

```
"images": [
      {
        "url":"https://picsum.photos/300"
      },
      {
        "url":"https://picsum.photos/400"
      }
]
```

as

```
"images": [
    { 
      image: {
        "url":"https://picsum.photos/300"
      }
    },
    { 
      image: {
        "url":"https://picsum.photos/400"
      }
    }
]
```

on SELECT

The count of nested items can vary.

[EDIT]

Sorry gays, the given code is incorrect JSON, this is how the field looks like in its entirety:

```json
{
    "images": [
      {
        "url":"https://picsum.photos/300"
      },
      {
        "url":"https://picsum.photos/400"
      }
    ]
}
```

to

```json
{
  "images": [
      { 
        "image": {
          "url":"https://picsum.photos/300"
        }
      },
      { 
        "image": {
          "url":"https://picsum.photos/400"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's the data type for your column? JSON? because this is not a valid JSON format.

Comment: @GRIV This is a fragment of a large JSON value. Column has JSON format.

Comment: Can you show the entire json value?

Answer (score 0):

You can present such a fragment in a string column. In other words, VARCHAR, CHAR, TEXT, etc.

You can't present a fragment of JSON in a column of JSON data type. MySQL's JSON type requires that the content be a valid JSON document.

The example you show is like a JSON object format, but missing the curly braces. That's not valid JSON.